# MATLAB — finding max value in a region of 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, 2d, max

Im having problem in finding how to find a max value in a defined region of 2D matrix. I need to find the coordinates, too.

Right now, I have this:

```
B ... 2Dmatrix <br>
[row_val row_ind] =max(B, [], 1) ;<br>
[col_val col_ind] =max(row_val) ;<br>
[r c] =find(B==max(B(:))) ;<br>
[s_v s_i] =max(B(:)) ;<br>
[r c] =ind2sub(size(B), s_i)<br><br>
```

It just finds the coordinates of the largest value, but I can't choose the region of the matrix to look for the max value.

Comment: -1: PLEASE show what you've attempted so far - what's worked? What hasn't? Make *SOME* attempt on your homework before you push it on us!  To all "MATLAB regulars": I would appreciate your input in the following meta-discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108521/168373

Comment: Consider doing a quick search before you ask a question that's going to waste people's time and clutter up the site.

Answer (score 4):

```
% extract region of interest
BRegion = B(rowStart:rowEnd, colStart:colEnd);

% find max value and get its index
[value, k] = max(BRegion(:));
[i, j] = ind2sub(size(BRegion), k);

% move indexes to correct spot in matrix
i = i + rowStart-1;
j = j + colStart-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How with matlab help? http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/max.html
there is also some examples. 
Here is some info about coordinates http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8136

Answer (score 0):

You're making this harder than you need to....there's no reason to flatten the matrix.

You're on the right track using `max` and `ind2sub`. For help with choosing the region, you might want to take a look at Matlab's own documentation on Matrix Indexing, in particular on Accessing Multiple Elements or Logical Indexing.

Answer (score 0):

This question requires thinking in terms of arrays and indices.

First, you need to identify the region you're interested in. If you don't have the coordinates of the sub-region, you can get them using e.g. [IMRECT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imrect.html)

```
%# create a figure and display your 2D array (B)
figure,imshow(B,[])
regionCoords = wait(imrect);

%# round the values to avoid fractional pixels
regionCoords = round(regionCoords);
```

`regionCoords` is an array with `[yMin,xMin,width,height]`, where `xMin` and `yMin` are the row and column index of the top left corner, respectively.

Now you can extract a sub-array and find the position and value of the maximum

```
xMin = regionCoords(2);
yMin = regionCoords(1);
xMax = regionCoords(2) + regionCoords(4) - 1;
yMax = regionCoords(1) + regionCoords(3) - 1;
subArray = B(xMin:xMax,yMin:yMax);

%# transform subArray to vector so that we get maximum of everything
[maxVal,maxIdx] = max(subArray(:));
```

All that's left is to get back row and column coordinates (using `ind2sub`) and to transform them so that they correspond to coordinates of the original array (`[1 1]` of `subArray` is `[xMin,yMin]` in the coordinates of the original array).

```
%# for the size of the subArray: use elements 4 and 3 of regionCoords
%# take element 1 of maxIdx in case there are multiple maxima
[xOfMaxSubArray,yOfMaxSubArray] = ind2sub(regionCoords([4 3]),maxIdx(1));

xOfMax = xOfMaxSubArray + xMin - 1;
yOfMax = yOfMaxSubArray + yMin - 1;
```

To check that everything worked, you can compare `maxVal` with `B(xOfMax,yOfMax)`.